# Destroy shapes on form close

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Currently when i click on a button it will create some shapes on a new form.  Once i close the new form how can i destroy the shapes it made.

I can add more info if needed but was hopeing there was a simple way to destroy all TMachine instances when the form closed.

`TMachine` is a TShape Class

```
procedure TFLayout1.GetClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  azone: string;
  adept: string;
  machine : TMachine;
begin
  fdb.count := 0;  //keeps track of number of machines in zone
  azone := MyDataModule.fDB.GetZone(Name);    //gets name of zone
  adept := TButton(Sender).Name;       //gets name of dept
  fdeptlayout.ListBox1.Clear;

  fdeptlayout.show;
  with fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1 do
    begin
         sql.Clear;
         sql.BeginUpdate;
         sql.Add('SELECT');
         sql.Add(' *');
         sql.Add('FROM');
         sql.Add(' `MList`');
         sql.Add('WHERE `Zone` = :myzone ');
         sql.Add(' AND `Dept` = :mydept');
         sql.EndUpdate;

         parameters.ParamByName('myzone').Value := azone;
         parameters.ParamByName('mydept').Value := adept;
         open;
    end;

  //gets number of machines in total
  while not fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.Eof do
    begin
      fdb.count := fdb.count+1;
      fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.Next;
    end;

  //restarts back at first query
  fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.First;

   //clears the last x value
   fdb.LastX :=0;

  //creates the shape
  while not fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.Eof do
    begin
        machine := MachineShape.TMachine.Create(self);
        machine.Parent := fdeptlayout;
        machine.PlaceShape(44,44,'CM402','first','123/33/123');
        fdeptlayout.ListBox1.Items.Add(fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Name').AsString);
        fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.Next;
    end;
end;
```

TMachine Class

```
unit MachineShape;


interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, extctrls,myDataModule,Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type

TMachine = class(TShape)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure PlaceShape(sizeW,sizeH :integer; name, order,asset : string);
  end;
implementation



    Procedure TMachine.PlaceShape(sizeW,sizeH :integer; name, order,asset : string);
    begin
       self.width :=  sizeW;
       self.height := sizeH;
       self.top := 136;
       self.left := MyDataModule.fDB.LastX +2;//set left
       MyDataModule.fDB.lastx := left + sizeW;
       showmessage(inttostr(mydatamodule.fDB.LastX));
    end;

end.
```

FDeptLayout

```
unit DeptLayout;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls,mydatamodule, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TfDeptLayout = class(TForm)
    ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  fDeptLayout: TfDeptLayout;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfDeptLayout.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin

end;

end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shown code is taking advantage of the [VCL ownership model](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Owner) and the form will free it for you, as you just pass the form itself as the owner of your components when you create it:

```
machine := MachineShape.TMachine.Create(self);
```

as this is called from the TFLayout1 class, when the particular instance of the form is destroying itself, it will free all the owned components.

For a little more info, you can read the article: [Owner vs. Parent in Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/owner_parent.htm).

## Edit

From comments, it resulted you create the `TMachine` instances on a class different of the form on which you show it, and you don't destroy the form instance when you close it, so, you can reach what you want making this changes:

- Make the form in which the shapes are shown the owner, changing your code to create them to this:

  ```
  //don't use self, now the parent is the instance referenced by fdeptlayout
  machine := MachineShape.TMachine.Create(fdeptlayout);
  ```
- On your Tfdeptlayout class, add a OnClose handler with this code:

  ```
  begin
    for I := ComponentCount - 1 downto 0 do
      if Components[I] is TMachine then
        Components[I].Free;
  end;
  ```

That said, you really have to read the documentation and referenced articles to gain some understanding of what's going on behind the scenes in your Delphi application.

Comment: But if i close the new form (with the shapes on it) then open it again the shapes are still there, even though when i open it the second time it should only show 4 shapes, Where first time it shows 13 .. if that made any sence

Comment: Do you destroy the form when you close it? Which type is the fdeptlayout variable? what is the TFLayout1 class?

Comment: TFLayout is a form that is creating the class TMachine,  the class TMachine is displayed on Fdeptlayout, another form.   FDeptLayout is the form i am closeing. But will call on that form again at some point.

Comment: How a _form_ can create a class? You have to pay atention at the words you use, otherwise is very hard to understand what you want to say. For example a Form (which makes me think about a runtime object also called a instance) cannot create a class, which is a mold used to create such object instances. A class can only be _created_ by the programmer, in the source code, before compiling the application.

Comment: by create class, i mean creating the instance ` machine := MachineShape.TMachine.Create(self);`

Comment: @Glen, please, also answer all my questions. You answered none of what I asked. Let's go 1 by 1 if you preffer: so, 

Do you destroy the form when you close it? (yes or not?)

Comment: Of which type is the fdeptlayout variable?

Comment: its a form I added it to OP

Comment: Do you mean added to your question? Since The OP is a person, in this case you: Original Poster.

Comment: AFAIK OP doesn't mean Original Post, it means **Original Poster**: the person who wrote the first version of the Question.

Comment: Take my advise, you really need to read the referenced documentation and articles, since IMHO you're starting to write too localized questions, which are closed by the community here.

Comment: there is alot of referenced documentation to read, i find i learn better by trying and examples.  I Do read after the fact to learn more about what i am doing but reading first does not always help. Where reading after does.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23472/discussion-between-jachguate-and-glen-morse)

Comment: On Edit,  It says TMachine is undeclared, is it best to just add TFormLayout1 to the uses or is there another way.  Sorr cant do chat , work blocks it.

Comment: Add your MachineShape unit to the uses clause of the DeptLayout unit.

Comment: Works perfect, Thanks a ton.  And if it makes you feel better i do understand why it works. Just never knew how to code it like that.

Comment: Ok, explain me why it works? I mean, I believe you, but just to be sure ;)

Comment: Now i am creating the shape on TFormLayout with TFormlayout as the owner thus not using (self).  So now when the form closes i can search for the component. or in this case searching for all components and freeing the ones that are TMachine type.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning an `Owner` to your `TMachine` objects.  The shapes will be freed automatically when the `Owner` itself is freed.

Assuming `TFLayout1` is your Form class, then by default it will not be freed automatically when it is closed.  A closed Form is hidden by default so you can re-show when needed.  To actually free it on close, you have to either set the `Action` parameter in the `TForm.OnClose` event to `caFree`, or call `TForm.Free()` directly sometime after the form is closed (such as if you are displaying the Form with `ShowModal()`, then you can call `Free()` after `ShowModal()` exits).

If you want to free the shapes yourself without relying on the behavior of an `Owner`, then set the `Owner` to `nil` when you create the shapes, and store your `TMachine` pointers in a `TList` that you can loop through when needed to free each shape, or a `TObjectList` with its `OwnsObjects` property set to true that you can `Clear()` when needed.  Such as in the Form's `OnClose` event.

Comment: i Rather owener do it,  So `TMachine` is created on `TFLayout1` but shown on `FDeptLayout`  So on close of `FDeptLayout` I need to ...lost after this lol

Comment: also if i call `free()` during the onclose,  Then if i try to open it again the form is no longer there, thus giving me access error.